# Worm in dry bread, what is it?

Tags: bread

I was picking up some bread and I noticed something moving in the box. After some searching I found the thing and it turned out to be a worm or a larva. Any idea what it is and should I start throwing everything out of the food closet?

Picture: (The worm is in two pieces in the middle)

*-You can right click and select "View Image" for a bigger picture.*

(Sorry if this is a wrong place to ask, this seems food related so I posted it here)

[image]

**-----     UPDATE     -----**

I found another one:

*-You can right click and select "View Image" for a bigger picture.*

For size comparison that stuff is the residue from the back of [this bread](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Q5Ky8QQRoX8/TduhcfQQquI/AAAAAAAAACs/PLAgN_4lt1s/s400/hapankorppu.jpg).
[image]

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/47522/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/5258/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/16849/67

Comment: Seems a bit small for a [mealworm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealworm). Can you give any size relation? How long has the bag been there?

Comment: @johannes_B I added a new picture for clarification. The bag has been there for a long time. For three or four months at the least.

Comment: Thanks @Joe! But those questions did not tell me what it is. But they did give me good info on how to store dry food in the future.

Comment: I really cannot tell what this is, but a little tip: Place a ruler next to it and show the thing in more detail. Somebody else may tell you something more helpful.

Comment: And as suggested in one if @Joe's links, have a close look at all dry stuff you have there and follow the rule: *When in doubt, through it out.*

Comment: Your second picture is probably a beetle larvae http://en.allexperts.com/q/Entomology-Study-Bugs-665/2010/10/worm-9.htm

Comment: "when in doubt, through it out" applies to spoiled food. Although gross in our culture there's nothing dangerous about eating bugs. They even turn some of that starch into useful protein!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are larvae of the Larder beetle, related to carpet beetles.  Vacuum up all the crumbs and keep the area clean.  They infest many dry foods and areas where food debris collects.

Comment: Thanks, I googled the things and it looks like a 100% match! I threw everything out and cleaned the cabinet. No sightings of them anymore and let's hope it keeps that way :).

Answer (score 0):

Oh man that looks eerily similar to carpet beetle larvae. I've had a bad run-in with them before where they had infested one of our bedrooms at one point.

Here's an image of the larvae:
[image]
[source](http://www.5star-termite.com/pest-identification/)

Are these larvae still alive? I would suggest checking your home to ensure they haven't infested it, as I have a feeling they would do poorly in a factory or even in a store.

Here's some more information:

> They all eat the same class of things – organic materials such as natural fibers (cotton, wool), fur, hair, skin, food, et cetera. Their eating habits often explain some of the confusion – because their larvae consume our dead skin, we often find them in or around our mattresses.

[source](http://www.edenpest.com/blog/post/a-flea-a-bed-bug-no-it-s-a-carpet-beetle)